# How to implement Pagination in Spanner when working with Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-spanner

I have below code for which there are 200 record. i need to implement pagination in this.

```
  Statement.Builder buildStatement = Statement.newBuilder(sql);
  List<EmployeeSpanner> spannerList= this.spannerTemplate
                .query(EmployeeSpanner.class, buildStatement.build(), null);
```

The SQL is created based on multiple logic and condition hence  i cannot use anything like `findAll`.

This is returning me 200 record and we need to send this to UI with pagination so that on first page only 25 record show and on second 25 and so on.

When done this for OLTP below is what we use to do but for Google spanner i need something similar.

```
 int countset= (int) (pageable.getOffset() > countOfRecord? 0 : pageable.getOffset());
        query.setFirstResult(countset);
        query.setMaxResults(pageable.getPageSize());

    return new PageImpl<>(query.getResultList(), pageable, countOfRecord);
```

Answer (score 1):

`SpannerPageableQueryOptions` has the `setLimit()` and `setOffset()` methods.

- Reference - https://googleapis.dev/java/spring-cloud-gcp/latest/com/google/cloud/spring/data/spanner/core/SpannerPageableQueryOptions.html

Note that if there is requirement of sorting of results then we will require to use `setSort()` method to support with a sorting implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To implement queries for pagination you need to configure `SpannerQueryOptions` with a `limit` and an `offset` to then pass it to the query.

```
SpannerQueryOptions spannerQueryOptions = new SpannerQueryOptions().setLimit(25L).setOffset(page * 25L);

Statement.Builder buildStatement = Statement.newBuilder(sql);
List<EmployeeSpanner> spannerList= this.spannerTemplate.query(EmployeeSpanner.class, buildStatement.build(), spannerQueryOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks. i have this import but it is not able to resolve setLimit() . import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.spanner.core.SpannerQueryOptions;

Comment: Take a look at the [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/cloud/gcp/data/spanner/core/SpannerQueryOptions.html#setLimit-long-) and make sure to use long numbers instead of integers.